# Two Columns, Same Data, Different Where Clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I'm needing to query the same column with two different WHERE clause statements.

I'm working with Magento and I'm unable to change the table format.

Table View: `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

```
entity_id | attribute_id | value                |
5         | 60           | Bear Apprentice      |
5         | 86           | bear-apprentice      |
5         | 71           | Item Description     |
5         | 74           | /a/p/apprentice2.jpg |
```

I would like to have it displayed as:

```
entity_id | Item Name            |  img                   |
5         |  Bear Apprentice     | /a/p/apprentice2.jpg   |
```

Ultimately getting `attribute_id 60` and `74` to appear on the same row but in two separate columns.
Is it possible to do a WHERE clause on a column alias?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the `attribute_id` ?

Comment: @Shaharyar Yes, I'm wanting to get attribute_id 60 and 74 in two different columns but on the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mySQL one way to pivot is to use `case` and `max` and `group by`.  This does assume an entity_Id can only have one paired value (1 attribute per value per entity) e.g. 60 can only appear once for entity 5.

```
SELECT entity_ID
     , max(case when attribute_Id = 60 then value end) as `Item Name`
     , max(case when attribute_Id = 74 then value end) as img
FROM tableName
WHERE entity_ID = 5
GROUP BY entity_ID
```